# How to get multiple PDF files with different name from web page JAVA

Tags: java, pdf

I'm trying to make a code that will download multiple PDF files with different name from a website

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        URL url = new URL("https://mywebsite.ca/blabla/public_docs/acetates/*PDFFilesArehere.pdf");
        InputStream in = (InputStream) url.openStream();
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C:\\Users\\elbb\\Documents\\MyFolder"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        in.close();
    }
```

Now the pdf files are on this path

```
URL url = new URL("https://mywebsite.ca/blabla/public_docs/acetates/--->...Here...<--");
```

is there any way to put them in a list? And eventually I will make a loop after and download them one by one

Any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you considered using  [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)? It's a very powerful Library that can parse HTML pages from Java and .net codes

So here what you can do

First declare your URL and make a regex for your files :

```
        String URL="https://blablabla.com\docs\"; //<---make sure that the PDF are listed and hosted here 
        // Declare list to add the files 
        ArrayList<String> pdfList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        //Regex pattern will detect if the files end with .pdf or .PDF
        String regex = "^.*\\.(pdf|PDF)$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Now here comes the fun part of Jsoup library :

```
    //This will automatically download the html page that contains the PDF and convert it to a document 
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
//Select the <a href="" > Attributes , as the pdf files are in those elements , it will also select all the <a href="" > elements 
Elements links =   document.select("a[href]");
```

But you are only interested in the links that contains PDF files right?

Do a loop that will sort and only add the element that contains the desired PDF files :

```
for (Element content : links)
        {
            String relHref = content.attr("href");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(relHref);

            while(matcher.find()) {
                pdfList.add(relHref);
            }
        }
```

Now , finally you can download your pdf files to a desired folder

```
        URL url = new URL(URL); //Connect to the host 
        InputStream in = (InputStream) url.openStream();

        for (String temp : pdfList) {

              url = new URL(URL+temp);// It will connect to www.blablabla.com\document1.pdf 
                  in = (InputStream) url.openStream();
                // Inside Workfolder directory every PDF files in the list will be created and will automatically name it self like it supposed to be 
                Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Evan\\Documents\\workFolder\\"+temp), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

                    in.close();
                }
```

Done ! Now open your directory and verify that all your pdf are there :)

Answer (score 0):

To download all PDF one by one 1st you need to grab all the file name and the you can loop it in same way, I believe below steps will help:

1) Parse the page/url where you have all PDF stored in server.

```
ex: https://mywebsite.ca/blabla/public_docs/acetates/ (this will show you the all file names which is available on server)
```

2) While parsing the data implement logic to separate file names from rest of HTML content and store the names in ArrayList or any collection you prefer.

3) Once above two steps are done loop/Iterate files name and put in your existing code.

You can use JSOUP for parsing HTML.

Comment: Very Interesting approach , But is  there a way to make the code automatically read the names of the PDF instead of manually write them in an array list? Your suggestion is very helpful but I was wondering If I can make it the most automatic possible

Comment: Yes It will be store automatically, you can use regex to separate file name from HTML and then at same time you can save it on any List or collection of your choice.